# CentOS port forward

Tags: iptables, firewall, linux-networking, port-forwarding

I have the following situation:

```
Internet ----- Server ------- virtual machine (kvm)
             public ip           192.168.122.12
              x.x.x.x
```

I need to make service on the port 3333 from the virtual machine to be accessible from the Internet.

Service 3333 is accessible from the Server.
I tested it using following command:

```
nc -v -w 5 192.168.122.12 3333;echo $?
```

I got Ncat: Connected to 192.68.122.201:3333

I tried this setting

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3333 -j DNAT --to 192.168.122.12:3333
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.122.12 --dport 3333 -j ACCEPT
```

But service is still not accessible from the Internet.
Can you help me?

Server and virtual machine has access to Internet.
When I just use:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:3333,fork TCP:192.168.122.12:3333
```

and enable 3333 on the server, everything is working.

Is it possible to do it using iptables? Where could the problem be?

**Update 1**
My plain iptables:

**iptables -t nat -L -n -v**

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 20 packets, 1750 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   21  1828 PREROUTING_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   21  1828 PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   21  1828 PREROUTING_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 4 packets, 240 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    4   240 OUTPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 4 packets, 240 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24     224.0.0.0/24        
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24     255.255.255.255     
    5   260 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
    0     0 MASQUERADE  udp  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24    
    4   240 POSTROUTING_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    4   240 POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    4   240 POSTROUTING_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 POST_public  all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    4   240 POST_public  all  --  *      +       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POST_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    4   240 POST_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    4   240 POST_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    4   240 POST_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain POST_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POST_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POST_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain PREROUTING_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   16  1568 PRE_public  all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    5   260 PRE_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain PREROUTING_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain PRE_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   21  1828 PRE_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   21  1828 PRE_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   21  1828 PRE_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain PRE_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain PRE_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain PRE_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

**iptables -L -n -v**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67
 1125  688K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    5   300 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    1   238 INPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    1   238 INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    1   238 INPUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    1   238 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   45  4548 ACCEPT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   52 13611 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 *       192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    2   113 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1049 packets, 1272K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
 1049 1272K OUTPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      +       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDI_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDI_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    1   238 IN_public  all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    0     0 IN_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    1   238 IN_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    1   238 IN_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    1   238 IN_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW


Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: What about ip_forward? Did you enable it? You can check ```cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward```

Comment: Thank you for answer. It is enabled. Your command returns 1.

Comment: Have you tried to run tcpdump on 192.168.122.12? Do you see any packets? What about default policy for FROWARD chain(ACCEPT or DROP)?

Comment: Do you have and Rules in filter/FORWARD or nat/PREROUTING prior to your own rules ?  Do the counters of the iptables rules increase as expected ? Does the VM have an appropriate default-route (use tcpdump to  identify in which direction packets are lost, as mentioned by @ALex_hha

Comment: @ALex_hha Default policy should be ACCEPT, Yes I tried tcpdump but nothing captured on 192.168.122.12. I have updated my question.

Comment: Can you replace the iptables output with that of `iptables -L -n -v ; iptables -t nat -L -n -v`?

Comment: @MadHatter I have updated my question.

Comment: any other firewalls  on the network through network that may block 3333?!

Comment: @F.sb Forwarding using socat is working, so there shouldn't be problem, I think...

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
```

reload `sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`

masquerade your private IP as your public when you go out to the internet (whichever interface owns the public IP)

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Nat imcoming requests back to you VM and port - presumably a bridge or tap device.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i virbr0 -p tcp --dport 3333 -j DNAT \
      --to 192.168.122.12:3333
```

don't drop it going out

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i virbr0 -p tcp --dport 3333 -d 192.168.122.12 -j ACCEPT
```